# MongoDb - cb is not a function

Tags: mongodb

I am having a little trouble when I am trying to insert into Mongo with node 5.x. I have created an ES6 class that has the Mongo collection as one of the properties of the class.  I trying to use the Mongo collection within a method on the same ES6 class to do the insert. The Mongo connection and the collection property is set when the class is constructed in a factory that creates the instance of the ES6 class. Within the factory I am creating a copy of the collection object by:

```
let collection = lodash.cloneDeep(this.collection);
```

and then passing into the ES6 class by

```
let newDoc = new Document (collection);
```

However when I called new._create()

I receive the stack trace below. I have also included the _create method for reference.

Any help would be appreciated,

G

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
            at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:346:3)
            at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:337:7)
            at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)
            at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:684:5)
            at Socket._write (net.js:694:8)
            at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)
            at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:278:5)
            at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:207:11)
            at Socket.write (net.js:618:40)
            at Connection.write (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:428:53)
            at _execute (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:411:24)
            at Pool.write (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:454:17)
            at executeSingleOperation (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:955:19)
            at Server.command (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1038:3)
            at executeWrite (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/wireprotocol/3_2_support.js:60:12)
            at WireProtocol.insert (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/wireprotocol/3_2_support.js:68:3)
            at Server.insert (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1066:37)
            at Server.insert (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:325:17)
            at insertDocuments (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:680:19)
            at insertOne (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:402:3)
            at Collection.insertOne (/home/user/git/DBStore/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:390:44)
            at Document._create (/home/user/git/DBStore/lib/document.js:222:20)
            at DescriptorModifier.updateDescriptor (/home/user/git/DBStore/lib/descriptor-modifier.js:28:38)
            at /home/user/git/DBStore/test/document-store-core-tests.js:240:47

_create(options) {

        let collection = this[_mongoCollectionSymbol];
        let attrs = this[_attributesSymbol];

        this._setFieldValue('updated_at', new Date());

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            collection.insertOne({ x:1 },
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    resolve(result);
                });
        });
    };
```

Comment: So why are you wrapping `.insertOne()` in a promise when it can return a promise natively? Food for thought.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried to call insertOne directly and still an issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your new code using the native promise, and also the context in which you are calling this. You clearly cannot possibly receive what is basically a *..callback not defined.."* error message if your promise chain and invocations are defined properly ( since there would be no "callbacks" if done properly). So they are not, which is the cause of the problem and the code we cannot see here.

Comment: Have you found the root of the problem? I'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, and I finally found the root cause. I noticed that you are cloning the collection. I was doing something similar using `lodash.merge`. This seems to somewhat "corrupt" the database instance, and some internals handlings does not work properly. If you remove the `cloneDeep` operation and just store the reference to the instance it will probably work, it did for me.

This is somewhat inconvenient, specially in cases like mine, where I don't want to clone the object at all, but just merge the properties in a safe manner. Hopefully for you the workaround is quite simple, for me it was a bit complicated to fix.

Hope this helps.